# Range based loop with a pair of strings C++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I have this function from my class

```
bool MyClass::verifyPair(const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& myPair) const { ... };
```

I need first value in for loop and I don't want to use this for:

```
for (int index = 0; index < myPair.first.size(); index++) { ... };
```

I wanna use a newer C++ loop and I've tried this but is not working:

```
for (auto& pairIndex : myPair.first) { ... };
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? The range based for on a string returns characters not indexes.

Comment: *"I need first value in for loop"* - just the first? Or all the others as well?If it is only the first then why loop at all?

Answer (score 2):

Your "newer C++ loop" is fine, you just shouldn't expect to get an index, but a value instead:

```
for (auto& c : myPair.first) {
    //do something with 'c' which is a char at a current position
}
```

In other words, `c` is equivalent to the value of `myPair.first[index]` in your regular for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

As you are looping on a string and as it is constant, you should say so in the foor loop:

```
for (auto ch: myPair.first) { ... }
```

Note that I changed the variable name because you get each character in the string and not an index.

If the object was bigger than a char, then you would use `const auto& ch` instead, but for a character, it's better to copy it.